# USB LAN/RJ45 Gigabit Ethernet Network Adapter which also serves as a USB 3.0 Hub

Tags: usb, networking, windows, ethernet, network-adapter

My laptop only has no Ethernet connection, but I've been successfully using [AX88179](https://www.asix.com.tw/en/product/USBEthernet/Super-Speed_USB_Ethernet/AX88179) (USB3.0 to 10/100/1000M **Gigabit** Ethernet Controller) for a few years now. Yet as soon as my Internet connection became higher than 100 Mbps, it seems I hit Asix' limit.

I've tried asking [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1510207/why-doesnt-my-usb-ethernet-card-asix-give-me-1-gbps) and was told it's probably because of the adapter (I've tried using both Cat5, Cat5e and Cat6 cables - the latter of which gave me 1 Gbps in another house).

I tried contacting Asix but they haven't even bothered to reply.

I therefore consider buying a new adapter, but the tricky part is my laptop only has 2 USB ports. One is USB 3.0 and the other is USB 2.0. If I understand correctly, only USB 3.0 can be used to achieve 1 Gbps.

In other words, the adapter I need should also serve as a USB 3.0 hub so I'll be able to connect other devices in general and other USB 3.0 devices particularly.

Do you know of any such device, which company is reputable enough to ensure I get 1 Gbps plus has technical support that actually replies?

What I want is:

[image: 1 Gbps Ethernet speed]

What I don't want and so far have is:

[image: 100 Mbps Ethernet speed]

Currently using:

[image: USB to Ethernet with hub adapter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with [Unitek 4-in-1 USB 3.0 Ethernet Hub](https://www.unitek-products.com/products/usb-3-0-3-port-hub-gigabit-ethernet-adapter). Unlike Axis, it doesn't even need a special driver!

[image: Unitek 4-in-1 USB 3.0 Ethernet Hub]